# JSON String loop and print

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string in this format

```
{"prey":["{\"distance\": 8.686924173343307, \"signal\": \"-59\", \"frequency\": 2447, \"mac\": \"00:00:00:00:00:00\", \"ip\": \"192.168.43.27\"}"]}
```

I am parsing this json using `var jsonSpy = JSON.parse(userList);`

what I am trying to do it get the distance out of it using the code bellow I have two variants both do the same thing. I can get it to output each individual array of distance, signal, frequency, mac and ip but can't get the individual bits of data as shown in the code bellow. I know the loop and the each do the same thing the json prints out a string but when I try to get the distance I get an undefined message not an error it just returns undefined.

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonSpy.prey.length; i++)
{
    console.log(jsonSpy.prey[i]);
    console.log(jsonSpy.prey[i].distance);
    ctx.fillRect(jsonSpy.prey[i].distance, 300, 20, 20);
}

$.each(jsonSpy.prey, function(i, item) {
    console.log(jsonSpy.prey[i]);
    console.log(jsonSpy.prey[i].distance);
    ctx.fillRect(jsonSpy.prey[i].distance, 300, 20, 20);
});
```

Comment: So you want the value of the distance?

Comment: If it's in that format, you'll need to use `JSON.parse(jsonSpy.prey[i])` to read the data.

Comment: @user4341206 http://jsonlint.com/ disagrees and says it is valid

Comment: Ok so do I need to parse it again inside the loop to get distance @Phylogenesis

Comment: Yes, in this instance `JSON.parse(jsonSpy.prey[0]).distance` will get the value you are after.

Comment: You nailed it can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: @Phylogenesis please provide it as an answer so he can accept it and the question doesn't show as 'unanswered' anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data inside `jsonSpy.prey[0]` is still stringified. In order to use the JSON inside, you'll need to run it through `JSON.parse()` again:

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonSpy.prey.length; i++)
{
    var innerJSON = JSON.parse(jsonSpy.prey[i]);

    console.log(jsonSpy.prey[i]);
    console.log(innerJSON.distance);
    ctx.fillRect(innerJSON.distance, 300, 20, 20);
}
```